# how to Iterate over two list of different size?

Tags: java, swift-mt

I have two Lists of swift tags.

```
List<SwiftTagListBlock> source_tagListBlock = source_block4.getSubBlocks("16R", "16S");
List<SwiftTagListBlock> target_tagListBlock = target_block4.getSubBlocks("16R", "16S");
```

How to compare the values in list in the swift blocks.

```
for (int i = 0; i < source_tagListBlock.size(); i++) {
    SwiftTagListBlock blockList = source_tagListBlock.get(i);

    Iterator<Tag> tagIterator = blockList.tagIterator();

    while (tagIterator.hasNext()) {
        Tag tag = (Tag) tagIterator.next();
        //System.out.println(tag.getName() + "    " + tag.getValue());          
    }
}
```

The above two list are of different size.
I want to compare the tag-name with the tag-values of another list.If there is any difference then write it to a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521434/iterating-two-lists-same-time-which-have-different-size?rq=1 and

Comment: I have asked this for comparing swift message blocks.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712698/how-to-compare-two-swift-mt-message?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution from this link. I will compare each of them tags by tags. If the tags are not found then write the differences.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37028146/5599600